# arsoft.tools.net(DNS Server) Redirect traffic from one URL to another (DNS forwarding)

Tags: c#, dns, arsoft.tools.net

Following the documentation of arsoft.tools.net on https://docs.ar-soft.de/arsoft.tools.net/, we just developed a dns server to intercept every request from the network, everything is working fine!

The thing that is slowing us down is: When the client types www.google.com (for example), we want to show or redirect to www.yahoo.com(or an IP address), any clue of how can we achieve that?

There is some people looking for the same solution here:
https://arsofttoolsnet.codeplex.com/discussions?searchText=redirect

Tks

**UPDATE 1:**

So far, this is what I have, but, redirecting is not working:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (DnsServer server = new DnsServer(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, 10, 10))
        {
            server.QueryReceived += OnQueryReceived;

            server.Start();

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop server");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    static async Task OnQueryReceived(object sender, QueryReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        DnsMessage query = e.Query as DnsMessage;

        if (query == null)
            return;

        DnsMessage response = query.CreateResponseInstance();
        //response.AnswerRecords.Clear();
        //response.AdditionalRecords.Clear();

        if ((response.Questions.Count == 1))
        {
            // send query to upstream server
            DnsQuestion question = response.Questions[0];

            if (question.Name.ToString().Contains("www.google.com"))
            {
                DnsMessage upstreamResponse = await DnsClient.Default.ResolveAsync(DomainName.Parse("www.yahoo.com"), question.RecordType, question.RecordClass);
                //DnsMessage upstreamResponse = await DnsClient.Default.ResolveAsync(question.Name, question.RecordType, question.RecordClass);

                foreach (DnsRecordBase record in (upstreamResponse.AnswerRecords))
                {
                    response.AnswerRecords.Add(record);
                }
                foreach (DnsRecordBase record in (upstreamResponse.AdditionalRecords))
                {
                    response.AdditionalRecords.Add(record);
                }

                response.ReturnCode = ReturnCode.NoError;
                e.Response = response;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What did you try already? For example, what about CNAME record from siteA to siteB?

Comment: Maybe you want to clarify what you mean by redirect. If just return IP of another site, then you can just respond with that IP (A record) or CNAME.

Comment: You want to do it so that when user types Google.com in browser to show page of yahoo.com, via DNS?

Comment: Yes, actually my really goal is to point some hosts to local ip address

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After some time, here is how to do:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        using (DnsServer server = new DnsServer(System.Net.IPAddress.Any, 10, 10))
        {
            server.QueryReceived += OnQueryReceived;

            server.Start();

            Console.WriteLine("Press any key to stop server");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }

    static async Task OnQueryReceived(object sender, QueryReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        DnsMessage query = e.Query as DnsMessage;

        if (query == null)
            return;

        DnsMessage response = query.CreateResponseInstance();
        DnsQuestion question = response.Questions[0];
        DnsMessage upstreamResponse = await DnsClient.Default.ResolveAsync(!question.Name.ToString().Contains("www.google.com") ? question.Name : DomainName.Parse("www.yahoo.com"), question.RecordType, question.RecordClass);

        foreach (DnsRecordBase record in upstreamResponse.AnswerRecords)
        {
            response.AnswerRecords.Add(record);
        }
        foreach (DnsRecordBase record in (upstreamResponse.AdditionalRecords))
        {
            response.AdditionalRecords.Add(record);
        }

        response.ReturnCode = ReturnCode.NoError;
        e.Response = response;
    }
}
```

If you want to point to some ip address:

```
static async Task OnQueryReceived(object sender, QueryReceivedEventArgs e)
        {
            DnsMessage query = e.Query as DnsMessage;
            if (query == null) return;
            DnsMessage response = query.CreateResponseInstance();

            if (response.Questions.Any())
            {
                DnsQuestion question = response.Questions[0];
                DnsMessage upstreamResponse = await DnsClient.Default.ResolveAsync(question.Name, question.RecordType, question.RecordClass);

                response.AdditionalRecords.AddRange(upstreamResponse.AdditionalRecords);
                response.ReturnCode = ReturnCode.NoError;

                if (!question.Name.ToString().Contains("yourdomain.com"))
                {
                    response.AnswerRecords.AddRange(upstreamResponse.AnswerRecords);
                }
                else
                {
                    response.AnswerRecords.AddRange(
                        upstreamResponse.AnswerRecords
                            .Where(w => !(w is ARecord))
                            .Concat(
                                upstreamResponse.AnswerRecords
                                    .OfType<ARecord>()
                                    .Select(a => new ARecord(a.Name, a.TimeToLive, IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.199"))) // some local ip address
                            )
                    );
                }

                e.Response = response;
            }
        }
```